# Automation script for website in loop

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, web

Below is the screenshot of the web pages, I need to write a script that add the product automatically, suppose 15 times.
    I achieved this for one single entry but i need to write it in a loop.
    Challenge here is that i need to select different categories based on which there are different sub-categories and based on sub-categories there are different sub-sub-category so can anyone suggest how to achieve this.

[image: Select Category]
[image: Select Sub-Category]
[image: Select Sub-Sub-Category]

Comment: [Don't do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361474/should-we-display-a-warning-when-users-include-images/361481#361481)

Comment: Thank You sir :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the fields and dropdown itself don't change you can create some kind of collection for each of the category options and sub options. Then with some mapping from one category to other you can achieve this.

Eg. CategoryArray will have [Item1, Item2, Item2] selection of this choice will guide which subcategory array you will access like Item1SubCategoryArray then so on and so forth.